# SonataMediaBundle - where are the relations between Media and Gallery defined?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have installed [the bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle) and everything is working properly, but I have a question. Where is the database mapping for the entities?

Looking [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/tree/master/Entity), in the Entity folder of the bundle, these classes extend each their respective class for the Model folder of the bundle. Looking at the [Gallery Model](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Model/Gallery.php), there are no annotations, so the mapping must be done in `Resources/config/doctrine` which it is.

However, the [Gallery](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/BaseGallery.orm.xml) mapping or the [GalleryHasMedia](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/BaseGalleryHasMedia.orm.xml) have all of the fields definition except the relation between the entities.

Is the relation created automatically? And how? Or is it somewhere else and I've missed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping is registered within the Extension class of the Bundle, see https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SonataMediaExtension.php#L194

Comment: Ah, I see. Why would they put it in there instead of the xml file, though?

Comment: It is to be able to handle configuration values such as class names, which you can't in an XML mapping file.

Comment: But you can [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html#parameters-in-configuration-files) or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: What you liked is a service description xml file, not a doctrine mapping file. Doctrine mapping doesn't support configuration (from the Configuration component) values injection.

Comment: OH, I SEE! Thank you for the clarification!